# React Navigation v6: How to set state variable of parent component from custom tab bar component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-v6, react-native-tabnavigator, react-navigation-top-tabs

I'm using React-Navigation v6 in my React Native app. I make a custom tab bar in my MaterialTopTabNavigator, and in it I have a TextInput in which I want to set a state variable in the parent component. Here's the render method of my parent component:

```
render() {

  const setParentState = (text) => this.setState({text})
  const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
  
  const TabBar = ({state, descriptors, navigation, position}) => {
    return (
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={text => setParentState(text)}
      />
    )
  }

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      tabBar={props => <TabBar {...props}/>}
    >
      ...
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}
```

So here I create a function `setParentState()` that calls `setState()` in the parent component. I try to call it from the `TabBar` component, but it doesn't successfully set the state in the parent component.

Why does it not set the state in the parent component? And how *can* I get it to do so?

```
"react-native": "0.69.10"
"@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.2"
```